# Automatically set created_by on model when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I am trying to automatically set `created_by` in my models to currently authenticated user without explicitly passing down user as an argument. I am using devise for authentication and for setting user globally on each request I am using new rails api `ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes` like so:

```
# app/models/current.rb

class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
end
```

```rb
# config/initializers/warden.rb

Warden::Manager.after_set_user { |user, auth, opts| Current.user = user }
```

Then I have `Owned` concern

```rb
# app/models/concerns/owned.rb

module Owned
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to(
      :created_by,
      class_name: "User",
      foreign_key: "created_by_id",
      default: -> { Current.user }
    )
  end
end
```

which is included in models in which I want to automatically set `created_by`.

It works but recently I got bug where `created_by` was assigned to wrong person and I am wondering if it could be caused by code I described above because its not thread safe. I am unable to reproduce the bug again and I don't know how to test for such potential race conditions. So my questions are: Is my usage of `CurrentAttributes` correct and my code in general? Is there a better way how to automatically set `created_by`?

Comment: Can you give details on how to reproduce that bug?